# I did not earn the Census Badge for this year's survey

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, survey-2018

**[2019-01-24 update] BUMP.**

(Yeah I'm not amused. One year and later and a couple more emails to support, I'm still ignored.)

---

I completed the 2018 developer survey, in January 24 if I'm not mistaken.

I understand the Census badge is awarded multiple times (https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census).

Some time after completing the survey, seeing I was not awarded the badge, I've reached for support through the Contact form (https://stackoverflow.com/contact) regarding this. But never got a reply, nor the resolution.

The issue remains. Not sure if posting here is the appropriate channel but I don't feel like simply trying the Contact form again as I got no feedback at all last time.

P.S. At the end of the Survey, I was asked for my email address so they could get in touch regarding some of my answers. But it did not ask for my profile link for the purpose of awarding the badge, like in 2017.

Comment: Same story with me (although I haven't used the contact form ;)

Comment: The reason we didn't ask for the profile link is because we've set it up to be better automated, you _should_ have gotten the badge after successfully completing the survey. Re-tagging this as a bug since you didn't. You're also welcome to follow up via our [contact form](http://stackoverflow.com/contact), I'm just making sure a dev sees this.

Comment: Do you recall where the link you followed to get to the survey originated? Did you follow it from the site, or perhaps from a retweet / email from someone else?

Comment: @TimPost for me, the link I followed originated from SO itself, but there perhaps was something wrong about the process I can't recall what exactly. I might have completed the survey in a private window or re-completed it after closing a tab with it..

Comment: @TimPost ah, no, I've searched through history and can say that I didn't use a private window. I can give all the hashes from urls, actually.

Comment: Marc, I guess this can help you too: search browser history for "survey" and copy all the urls related to SO survey: they contain some hashes that can be helpful for isolating/solving the problem

Comment: Hi @TimPost, the link I did use came as an email titled "Last chance! 2018 Developer Survey closes Fri, Jan 26".

Comment: Thanks @YakovL. Dear TimPost, just let me know if it's needed - I've since reinstalled my OS, but the links might still exist in my backups.

Comment: @TimPost I had the same issue and filled out a contact form, but got an email suggesting to post on meta which I just did. After reading the comments, I checked and I still have the links in my browser. What do I do next? (Marked the question I just posted as duplicate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm awarding last year's Census badge to the following users:

- [Marc.2377](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3258851/marc-2377)
- [YakovL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3995261/yakovl)
- [soupwaylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5701065/soupwaylee)

If you did not get the badge and *did* take the survey (and swear on your Stack Overflow reputation that you did ;-), ping me and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @AndreSilva: I awarded the badge for you. Enjoy!