# Take the 2019 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2019

Our annual survey, now in its ninth year, launches today and anyone who codes is encouraged to participate. The survey will be open until February 12.

[Take the survey](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_medium=so-meta&utm_source=so-owned&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019)

We heard you loud and clear when you asked for a shorter survey. We did our best to deliver without sacrificing valuable insight, and we shaved off about five minutes from last year’s survey. The survey should take about 25 minutes to complete.

Any user who completes the survey in its entirety will have the option to get the Census badge on Stack Overflow or a different technical site in the Stack Exchange network.

Keeping with tradition, anonymized survey results will be available publicly under the Open Database License. You’ll be able to download and analyze the dataset later this year. Certain survey answers are treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore excluded from the anonymized results. These questions are highlighted in the survey with a note saying, “This information will be kept private.”

Thanks in advance for your time and thoughtfulness.

**If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages**
Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey.

Comment: Does it have questions on job satisfaction, if the answerer is looking for work, or other things that probably shouldn't be answered from a work computer?

Comment: @DanNeely In a very _general_ way, but if in doubt, take it at home perhaps. As a manager I don't think there's anything that would worry me, but I have little experience being a crummy manager, so better to be safe.

Comment: `Have you tried turning it off and on again?` Assuming it was related to the previous question, I tried to reboot my familly, but now it won't start up

Comment: Plenty of questions in here that are too vague, make no sense, and don't have appropriate options.

Comment: The survey is not loading. I've been looking at a spinning thingamabob for a minute now. Is this just that too many people are trying to do the survey at the same time?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Haven't been able to replicate that, and you are the only one so far who has surfaced that issue. Perhaps try refreshing?

Comment: @AnitaTaylor good team work on the length of the survey, bravo! Delayed my snack time to do the survey, looking forward to the interesting results! PS: Bonus-my 100th silver badge :)

Comment: @JeremyBanks We have heard the community loud and clear that our results do not represent ALL developers. We will be framing the results this year with that in mind.

Comment: For anyone running into the same issue I have (survey not loading): Disabling content blockers did the trick for me.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Would the first page not even load? It says there "please disable ad/content blockers to see the survey"

Comment: @ArunVinoth Whoops! Orkut is retired. We removed Orkut and replaced it with Hello, the social media app released by Orkut's founder. Thanks for bringing to our attention

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, I didn't get to see that message until **after** I disabled the ad blocker. :D

Comment: Skipping questions works  I extensively tested it. On a more serious note, a lot of questions made me wonder as to what their relevance was.

Comment: @TimPost I'm not overly concerned at my current employer; but my previous ones it dept would use its https mitm proxy to break the protection on the 'anonymous' surveys HR sent out.  While it could've been stupidity not malice my paranoia was redlined after seeing that.

Comment: I would like to nominate myself for *"who is going to be the most influential person in tech?"*. If elected, I promise to be influential. Please write in **Evan Carroll** -- two 'r's, two 'l's. All power to the people!

Comment: @CrisLuengo I had no problem running uBlock Origin on Firefox.

Comment: The current line of questions and answers regarding mental health issues is a huge improvement in comparison to last year. Well done, and thank you!

Comment: At the end it thanks for taking "the test survey". When can we expect the real one to be released :P ?

Comment: If the survey is too invasive to work with my company's security settings, I'm certainly not going to trust my home network to that same invasion.

Comment: @Prune from opening it and looking at the 1st few screens it appears that it's entirely hosted on a single domain (ABP and privacy badger didn't find a thing); but since it's being run by an analytics company some people have probably blacklisted the domain itself and thus will have it go boom even directly on their site not just when it tries to load crap onto 3rd parties.  I suspect it's mostly an issue for people who use hostfile blocking methods.

Comment: @dwirony The survey this year is one of the shortest annual surveys I've taken at SO (and I've taken it at least for five years).

Comment: @TylerH I'll probably delete my comment because it's so petty, but I just feel like the length of it is going to hurt response numbers...

Comment: In related news, **[I still haven't got my badge for the last year's survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364515/3258851)**.

Comment: I'm the kind of person that thinks that if a site doesn't work while addblockers are turned on, it's a site I don't want to visit. Why not just make a survey without snooping on it's users?

Comment: "Xcode" is still spelt like that. With a lower case C.

Comment: @Geremia It will take us several weeks to analyze the data, build the results page, etc. We don't have a firm launch date yet, but we will promote that the results are ready on all of our channels on launch day.

Comment: There is some weird behavior by the survey on Firefox - if you click the browser back button by accident to get back to the previous question, then click the back button on the survey because the former did not work, you have to start all over again. Maybe it was just bad luck, in any case rather annoying. Would be great if it would work "by least surprise" that is neither back button should destroy answers without warning. Hope this helps.

Comment: Seeing as there are numerous job related questions anyway, I feel that there should have been questions about people's work machine configurations, and maybe that would help correlate developer happiness and hardware power.

Comment: @Matty I passed the survey with AdBlock Plus without any issue. But maybe it's not blocking enough stuff ...

Comment: When are the results available? Oh I guess after Feb. 12 some time.

Comment: I took the survey, got the badge, but I'm still seeing "Take the survey" banner after I login. I bit redundant, I must say.

Comment: What if I took the survey on a different browser while I wasn't logged in. How can I claim that I actually took it from the browser that I'm logged in on?

Comment: @LucasRamage You should have seen a screen that asked you to login or sign up.

Comment: Shaving off 5 minutes is impressive! ...on a 10 minute survey. The survey takes 25 minutes? Ain't nobody got time for that!

Comment: I did, but I didn't have access to my credentials at the time (big long password stored in pass). When I got home to my personal machine I couldn't find the link.

Comment: Is there no way to have "Palestine"/"State of Palestine"/"Occupied Territories of Palestine" as a country option? I know there's the "Other countries" option, but having another option seems better.

Comment: I took the survey, but didn't get the badge. I am still seeing Take the survey link. Is there anything else to do to get the badge ?

Comment: geo-blocking sucks. Ipism http://en.speedypedia.info/Ipism

Comment: sometime, user add negative mark without proper reading question or answer

Comment: @AnitaTaylor I am still waiting for Census badge. :(

Comment: @TaimoorAdilBadshah I will pass this on to our Customer Support Team, and they will manually award the badge.

Comment: Now that the survey is closed, maybe it shouldn't be featured on Meta anymore. *grumble, grumble, arbitrary deadlines in the fine print*

Comment: Hey @Zim Should be down now. The featured tag was actually removed a bit before your comment but the box caches stuff for a while, so it was still listed there for a bit. Thanks for letting us know. :D

Comment: When will the results be announced? It has been a couple of months!

Answer (score 274):

> Would you like to see any of the following on Stack Overflow? Check all that apply.
>
> Industry news about technologies you're interested in

Please no. It already exists on LinkedIn and it feels more like a PR campaign and spam than anything else.

These companies can already provide that information in the job offers. To provide them with a new way of getting information fed to us, would be **in my opinion** bad.

StackOverflow should not expand into this. It should stick to what it does best; offer a professional Q&A site.

Comment: *Please no.* - goes for all of the options this question provided

Comment: @TimCastelijns I agree, however that one in specific just hit me in the head. Also the other options were: 1. Tech meetups or events in your area, 2. Tech articles written by other developers, 3. Courses on technologies you're interested in

Comment: @kemicofa I'd like more **English**-speaking tech meetups in my area.

Comment: [NO GOD! NO GOD, PLEASE NO, NO, NO, NOOOOO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H07zYvkNYL8)

Comment: I disagree - the option does not state *how* these "news" should be structured. If it were a neutral facts- and votes-based, collaborative list of news events to specific tags, it could grow into something helpful.

Comment: in theory I was okay with the tech articles idea personally, but I wasn't sure what that would look like; is it blogs anyone can create / vote on, and how would that differ from QA pairs? Personally I always felt like the "question" part of the selfie Q/A workflow could use some help, right now posting a selfie Q/A pair is pretty risky and it's hard to judge whether it'll be successful enough to avoid the roomba. I guess I was interpreting that answer as "we're going to improve the selfie Q/A workflow somehow".

Comment: Yeah, because [that worked great for documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) @Blauhirn. Voting works on Q&A because there are definitive answers. It doesn't work on "news" or documentation because one mans meat is another mans poison. Vote to close, primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Cœur I agree that it would be nice but stackoverflow's original focus had nothing to do with meetups. There could eventually be a subdomain (similar to meta) meetup.stackoverflow.com / social.stackoverflow.com but that still needs to be extensively discussed.

Comment: StackOverflow has an awesome niche --- a repository of the best answers to the best questions.  Deviation far from this will only serve to defocus SO and make it less useful, IMO.

Comment: One of my comments on how to improve SO was to emphasize its original goal (becoming a repository of knowledge). Couldn't agree more with your answer.

Comment: I would not read it as I don't even have time to read all of www.theregister.co.uk

Comment: @apnorton By itself a Q&A site is not a sustainable business model- SO needs revenue for staff, maintenance, infrastructure, expansion etc. so the jobs and marketing part of SO are very much a crucial component

Answer (score 161):

> How do you feel about the quality of open source software (OSS)?
>
> - OSS is, on average, of HIGHER quality than proprietary / closed source software
> - The quality of OSS and closed source software is about the same
> - OSS is, on average, of LOWER quality than proprietary / closed source software

I don't think this is a good question for the survey, personally. Each piece of software, each library, each app is so wildly different from the next and written by so many different authors that you can't begin to average them meaningfully this way.

Further, the nature of proprietary/closed-source software makes it harder to compare quality as you typically only see the front end interface of such software... you don't know how well it is written, whether that is efficiency, elegance, or some other metric.

Likewise, this question:

> Does your company regularly employ unit tests in the development of their products?

Has two "no" options, but each one includes a strong opinion, either 'I'm glad this is the case' or 'I wish this were the case'. Where are the options for "No, and I don't really care one way or the other"?

I would prefer if you could insert a "No opinion" option for these types of questions, at least in the future. Or make it clear that you can leave it blank... which reminds that these radio button questions also need a way to clear the selection; going back and then moving forward again doesn't clear a question's choices, and once you've finished a section it seems like you aren't able to go back and change your answer.

Comment: I liked that question, had to think twice before answering yes, but it's a well defined question IMHO! A "No opinion" would be a good idea I guess...

Comment: I came here for this question also. It gives you 3 blanket-statement options and no "No Opinion" or "Other". That remark comes up every year...

Comment: @gsamaras I suppose it could be a nice question for people who have an informed opinion. I rarely look at the code for OSS projects, and no one looks at the code for closed source projects (unless they're the developer for it). I *may* have been able to provide a realistic answer if it said "OSS on average *feels* like it's higher/lower quality" or even better if it asked something specific (what does it mean by quality? again... could be elegance, efficiency, intuitive/more accessible UX/UI, a better/more modern visual design, ad infinitum...)

Comment: @TylerH: It doesn't explicitly ask about the **code** quality. I guess they mean overall quality (performance, usability, features, documentation, ...)

Comment: @BDL That's kind of my point.

Comment: Personally, I'de say there's worst. I mean, the question is "what are your general feeling about this, with all your current experience" I think it's a legit question, just not well defined enough. But a no opinion checkbox would be great too

Comment: "On average" is, when asking about subjectivity, what's your general feeling about. Average is a measurement of central tendency. If you believe tha OSS has the tendency to be better, same or worse than non-OSS, then answer that.

Comment: @Braiam The definition of "on average" is not directly related to what metric we are using as a comparison. Giving a subjective explanation of what a question is asking for regarding a subjective matter also does not really solve anything.

Comment: @TylerH what the heck are you talking about? I'm telling you that the question and selection are fine as is. You can have subjective comparison about a group of software and what you feel it's more likely (which is what "on average" means) to tend towards good or bad. Quality is not a entire quantitative measure, and expecting that it would be is a poor design, but you are the only one doing that observation, not the survey which asked you "How do you feel". The issue that Kreiri mentions is more important design of the survey, this question makes sure to measure subjective impressions.

Comment: @Braiam Ignoring your rude tone, I'm saying your comment is 1) an opinion others don't necessarily share, and 2) conflating two parts of the survey question. The question asks for how we feel about something without defining it and without giving us adequate options to choose from. That seems straightforward to me; what part am I losing you on?

Comment: I *think* it was the Code Review question that also had two options that were "I perform code reviews because I think it's beneficial" and "I perform code reviews because I am told to do so". I would've optimally chosen "both", however I understand that one or the other gets the point across fine. I just hope that in the end, a result in favor of the latter isn't misinterpreted as *"Most of you do code reviews, but only because you're forced to."*

Comment: "How do you feel about the **quality of open source software (OSS)**?" doesn't include the "it"? What do you believe is quality is up to your own subjective impressions and something no one will ever agree about. They are already asking you how do you feel, keeping the same "feeling" for the rest of the question isn't a stretch.

Comment: This question in particular had one big issue that others shared a bit:  All three answers were valid depending on which team in my company it was talking about.  I chose my answer for my team, but the results aren't going to be correct since it assumes "company".

Comment: I picked lower quality, since _on average_ open-source is of godawful horrible quality. Then of course there's stuff like gcc,Gimp, SVN, Codeblocks etc that are of very high quality. But the average hobbyist open-source project on Github is mostly trash.

Comment: I think a better question would have been "Consider the top 10% of open source software and the top 10% of closed-source software, in terms of quality.  Which is better?"  ...or something along those lines.  OSS has a fat tail of super low quality software, but I'd contend the top ~10% of OSS is better than the top 10% of commercial software.

Comment: @Braiam I agree that it is subjective but that no-one agrees about it is not true. For this question to be comparable, how they define quality, and how they would measure that what they defined (if they even defined it) should be clear and would probably be a questionnaire itself.

Comment: Interesting discussion. I picked higher quality because I limit my view of OSS to be serious and well-maintained projects, not hobbyist stuff thrown on Github. the latter I would simply never use in production software so I didn't even count them in.

Comment: It's also bad that the question specifically states *unit* tests. If my projects have automated tests that don't test in isolation (e.g., maybe they interact with the DB or actually invoke an end-to-end web request) using a unit test framework, do they have "unit" tests? "Unit test" has many definitions, and many developers strongly disagree on which one is correct.

Answer (score 87):

I have completed the developer survey three times in the past years. To my surprise, I was just about to visit the survey page and faced this message:

> **Access Denied**
>
> You don't have permission to access "http://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_1RGiufc1FCJcL6B?" on this server.
>   Reference #18.4fdf3a17.1548274458.be71ce39

It looks like this ban is country-based and it is inaccessible for Iranian users. Because when I switched to VPN, I got no such message.

**Update**

Thank you all for the support and care about unjust issues like this. Apparently, the ban has now been lifted up. I was able to visit the survey page from three different locations without any problems, and got my Census badge just now.

I would like the other users who are still unable to access the page, to leave a comment or inform the SO staff.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379352/560648

Comment: Goddamn. If I'd known about this, I'd've refused to take the survey on principle. Hey, staff, you want to know what a *real* example of not being inclusive and welcoming looks like? How about *banning entire regions of the world* from accessing your service?

Comment: Yeah that's ... ungood.

Comment: @MarkAmery apparently US law in this area is *extremely* restrictive to companies choice of actions.

Comment: @DaveInCaz That's not my understanding. I've frequently read that the mere exchange of information over the internet is usually exempt - which seems likely to be true given that US-based social media sites manage to allow Iranians to access them just fine. After a little Googling, I'd expect everything Stack Overflow offers to fall under the broad permission for US companies to export services providing "personal communications over the Internet" to Iran in [General License D-1](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/iran_gld1.pdf).

Comment: @DaveInCaz In any case, if they've spoken to their lawyers and found that, for some bizarre reason, it's illegal for US companies to allow to allow Iranians to participate in surveys (but oddly not illegal to let them participate on Jobs, as I just confirmed by changing my location to Tehran), then Stack Overflow should say that, and apologise to the people they're blocking. Instead they seem to have just not considered the issue at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm not a lawyer but I thought most kinds of "doing business" (my choice of words) in Iran was restricted and that may extend to companies you would subcontract with. (Also a few other places such as Cuba, N. Korea). I'm not sure exactly how "doing business" is defined. I've also seen some degree of uncertainty in this area which may cause people to behave even more conservatively than is actually necessary (?). In any case I agree with you that they should be clear and explain the situation!

Comment: @MarkAmery Sounds like you missed that the survey is implemented by a third party. So, more specifically, SO selected the firm Qualtrics without investigating whether all of their user base is permitted to use Qualtrics technology, or did investigate but went ahead anyway. And that's either better or worse. (I'm assuming it was the not-bothering/realising/checking/considering approach, since SO itself does not appear to geo-block anybody.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't miss that - we're saying more or less the same thing here. SO didn't *need* to use Qualtrics; they could've trivially rolled their own solution. That they didn't do so points to - as you say - this issue either not being considered or being accepted deliberately as a tradeoff to save a few extra man-hours of work.

Comment: @MarkAmery  (& https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379318/why-i-cant-open-the-2019-developer-survey-link/379352?noredirect=1#comment665178_379352)

Comment: @MarkAmery FWIW changing your location to Tehran in Jobs is not the same thing; the check runs based on where your IP is geolocated. Case in point - the OP here was blocked from taking the survey without ever filling out a 'what country are you located in' field.

Comment: This is the 2nd year that Stack Overflow used Qualtrics as our survey provider. Unfortunately, Qualtrics Terms of Service blocks countries where there are US sanctions. Based on our experience using them last year, we didn’t realize this was going to be an issue. We chose Qualtrics because our survey requires more specialized functionality than we can build in-house. Although the survey itself is large in scale, the team of employees who work on it is quite small, so we need to automate where we can. Next year, we will keep this issue in mind and determine if Qualtrics is the right fit.

Comment: ... You've got an army of software developers chomping at the bit to do other people's work for them. I'm sure they could come up with a survey software for you ;-). @AnitaTaylor

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Do you have any plans to solve it for this years surveys, because if it isn't done, you cannot say that there was a world wide survey in the resulting blog post of the survey, since that will be lies

Comment: @Ferrybig And the announcement post's title is "Our 2019 Developer Survey is Open to Coders Everywhere!"!

Comment: @MarkAmery I mean, iirc social media / chat platform facilitating services have started outright banning and deleting users from sanctioned areas as well. See: the recent slack controversy where slack will delete your account if you've logged in from any sanctioned part of the world. If the interpretation of these sanctions by the US administration evolves further, it could be concievable that even SO would have to eventually follow this course of action.

Comment: Its unfortunatel but as the recent incident with huawei, proves the US likes using its international muscle to force the world to comply with their international policy. so its hardly suprising that US based companies are even more worried about being persicuted for violating it

Comment: Idk why people are reacting so strongly to this. It clearly wasn't SE's fault or intention...

Comment: geo-blocking sucks. Ipism http://en.speedypedia.info/Ipism

Answer (score 75):

> Imagine that you are deciding between two job offers with the same compensation, benefits, and location. Of the following factors, which 3 are MOST important to you?

Family friendliness (such as providing child care options, financial support for Kindergarten etc.)is not listed but should be considered an important factor at least to me this is a top priority.

Comment: I dont remember this question, may be I clicked Next twice :)

Comment: It is placed somewhat between your annual income and when you last time prepared your CV

Comment: That's great feedback; thank you for sharing.

Comment: Note, in certain jurisdictions (read Countries, but wte) some of these "perks" are mandatory.

Comment: But do such jurisdictions outweighs those, where these  "perks" are not mandatory (on a global scale)?

Comment: @Jankapunkt have you seen someone moving from one country with perks towards one without?

Comment: I have nothing but a guess: Germany to * but my initial argument was not only about quantifiable perks but also the family friendliness of the company as a whole. What, if something unexpected happens (which is to be expected with children) and you are suddenly unavailable? Is the company prepared for it and covering you or will you be blamed? Will it affect your career in the long term?

Comment: @Braiam I think that more than one person has moved from, say, Britain to, say, the United States...

Comment: That's a nation-specific, so it would be a bad option to add. For example in Sweden, you pay a low monthly fee (roughly 100€) which is about as much as you get from the government through childbenefit. In other words it is paid by taxes and it doesn't make any sense for a company to offer it as a bonus.

Comment: As I said before it is not only about perks. If I have to leave early because of an incident with my child, will this affect my career? How is the company prepared for that? Family friendliness is to me a universal concern and not exclusively a national or financial one.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Then you would get paid by the government, "healthcare of child". And if the company discriminates you because of that, they end up in court. Just not in your country.

Comment: What about quality of code and the work process?

Comment: financial aid with child care and health care is usually listed as a compensation or benefit which were explicitly excluded from the question

Comment: Okay again, family friendliness is more than just financial benefits and child care.

Comment: How is that not even an option? Having kids and raising them is kind of one of the main functions of the human race. It's literally one of the few things that every culture in history shares. Who wrote this survey?

Answer (score 58):

I've finished the survey, got my `Census` badge, but I still have the bar at the top:

> Make your voice heard. Take the 2019 Developer Survey now [x]

Clicking the link says

> You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired.

It would make more sense to simply remove this bar for those who have already completed the survey.

Comment: AFAIK the survey is [not linked to your user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey?cb=1#comment664762_379294), so main SO won't know you completed it.

Comment: This might be based on presence of the `Census` badge earned during the survey (with some logic regarding the possibility to earn it for other network site than SO).

Comment: I think that badge can be earned annually. I guess checking the day the badge was obtained.... Also you don't necessarily need to claim the badge if you do not want. Perhaps they thought this was too complicated, considering you can click in the small `x` in the top left and make the message go forever.

Comment: Finished the survey and realized I've done this in Incognito mode, agreed to take Census badge, logged in... And now I have Census badge and able to take the survey again! Without even "You have already completed...or expired" message.

Answer (score 52):

I think this question is not clear

> Think back to the last time you solved a coding problem using Stack Overflow, as well as the last time you solved a problem using a different resource. Which was faster?

The problems can be different requiring different implementation efforts after looking at a resource. Also faster is quite subjective. Faster what? Coding, searching or something else?

Comment: I too thought this question wasn't very good. Also, why "the last time" only? But yes "coding problem" is not very well defined. I look at docs all the time to check for the right order of parameters or the spelling of a function name (which is very fast). And when I cannot solve something, I usually search the docs first and Google then (which typically will take me to SO), so it's 50/50. And when they say "using Stack Overflow", does it mean in general, or asking a new question? That's quite different I think... In the end I have to kind of guess what they are trying to know and answer that.

Comment: The question clearly asks which way is more effective. So apply the necessary scalings and subtractions.

Comment: I think it is subjective and can't be decided. I mentioned what is not clear to me.

Comment: After choosing "about the same", I went back and then chose "slightly faster", and saw that it asked me to estimate how much time I'd saved on Stack Overflow. This is not something I can estimate and is an invalid question: I didn't save time, I just researched until I found the answer. Sometimes that answer was on SO, sometimes it was on official documentation. Am I meant to look into the alternate timeline where I didn't find that SO result for a point of comparison?

Answer (score 47):

> Which social media site *etc*
>
> - ...
> - WhatsApp
> - ...

Why have you included WhatsApp, a *messaging app*, in a list of social media sites? Surely you should then also include SMS, phone calls, and letters. Semaphore flags. Smoke signals. You get my point.

Comment: It can be used to broadcast messages, and set statuses, it's not just geared towards it in te same way other sites are.

Comment: You can have groups with written pseudo-permanent content in WhatsApp while any other "service" you quote can't. You can Google things to see that many people in some countries use it more than Facebook or other "classic" social media

Comment: Ask anyone who uses Reddit on a regular basis and they'll tell you it's not a social media platform either

Comment: WhatsApp is also not really a site. All the others were at least sites.

Comment: Smoke signals. XD

Comment: WhatsApp is an et cetera.  I see no problem here.

Comment: Social media *platform* would have been the correct term here. It is somewhat "social media" thanks to status etc.

Comment: By the way, I consider Stack Overflow as a social media : there is interaction with established users, diffusion of information, notifications, lots of time lost browsing new user-created content, that's enough for me to consider it as social media. Wasn't listed in the survey, but at least there was a freetext box

Comment: @SeinopSys soon...

Answer (score 44):

[A large group of people visit Stack Overflow to curate the content, and to moderate the site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). This question seems to be missing them.

[image]

Would it be possible to add a  "Moderate the content of Stack Overflow" as an option?

Comment: Isn't that covered under "contribute to a library of information"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, that would be answering questions, rather than curating them.

Comment: I don't think any good can come of saying that moderation is not a contribution to the site.

Comment: I also don't think any good can come of the idea that people who don't produce content (whether Qs _or_ As) should be moderating, but that's a different barrel of worms.

Comment: True, moderation is infact one of the most important contributions to the site. It certainly needs its own separate option. There are people who visit the site just to ask and answer posts, and there are some (like me) who visit the site to just curate the content.

Comment: All right, I see what you mean about calling it out. Agree to disagree, though.

Comment: Sure, we all do have our own view points, and might necessarily not overlap.

Comment: @BhargavRao I disagree; moderating *is* contributing, and in some ways is far more meaningful/important than answering/asking. I would recommend that the verbiage be changed to something else, though, e.g. "Curating a library of information" or adding a parenthetical that says (Asking, answering, editing, or moderating).

Comment: @TylerH, that's precisely what I want too. The "curating a library of information" is ambiguous and does need to be clarified.

Comment: I was surprised there wasn't an answer like simply "gain more rep". This is, I think, sensibly different to "contribute to a library of information", and I'm pretty sure a lot of people would check that - note I'm not saying whether that's a good motivation, but it's definitely one (and honestly, to an extent, on of the points of the rep system).

Comment: It is covered by "Pass time and relax". Now get back to clearing that flag queue!  :)

Comment: @Lundin, I did end up choosing that option. :-) ... and hey! the flag queue has been almost empty these days ..

Comment: Needs an option for `Close questions` because there are some people here who never do a single other thing.

Comment: @BhargavRao I disagree that moderating and curating content is distinct from "contributing." But the option could be clearer. If you're in favor of just modifying the text (as the comments suggest is possible), you might want to edit your answer.

Comment: +1 I moderate and edit. When I read "contribute to a library" I thought "adding content to it", because that is how contributing works when it's contributing to a library. I revise and prune SO's content, I do not add to it, therefore I didn't tick this box.

Answer (score 41):

> Think back to the last time you updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What is the PRIMARY reason that you did so?

I just like to regularly keep my CV up to date, why is there no 'other' or 'just because' reason for this?

Also, clicking a radio button here makes me unable to 'deselect' it and press 'next' without choosing anything.

Comment: I think it's covered by either "learned new skills" or "got a new job". What was the primary reason you last updated your resume? Was it to change your job/job history? Or your skills? If both, just pick one.

Comment: neither? maybe i just came across it and realized it was old or missing something. I think i just left this one blank.

Comment: @TylerH It might, I was more implying reconstructing / rewriting parts of your resumé regarding 'keeping it up to date'. In addition, there could be a non-work related reason, like applying for a scholarship as a reason to update it.

Comment: @KevinB What was it missing? What do you put on a resume except your skills and your past work experience?

Comment: I added things i'm interested in to it. Not new skills, new work experience, new schooling, etc, things that were simply missing.

Comment: Personally I "updated it" (made one) to interview for a job I was recommended to by a jury member in a competition, and I really had no clue what option to choose here. "Something changed" was my pick but it did not feel entirely right.

Comment: @TylerH My reason was "time", I simply wanted to keep it updated just in case

Comment: @TylerH maybe you have changed contact details, gender, name

Comment: +1 I just had to pick "something else changed". My actual reason was "I happened to see my SO developer story, and decided I wanted to update it".

Answer (score 40):

> Which of the following platforms have you done extensive development work for over the past year? (If you both developed for the platform and want to continue to do so, please check both boxes in that row.
>
> *- Slack*

Does Slack qualify as a *development platform*? Seems to me it's a sneaky way of recruiting former Slack developers ;).

Comment: I was surprised at this as well... seemed like a clear "one of these is not like the others"... but I don't use Slack so what do I know?

Comment: That was the hidden IQ test... Spot the difference. Joke, tbh I use it daily but left it because I never developed it or for it.

Comment: Well someone has to be writing all the 3rd party integration's slack has...

Comment: Sure but why Slack? Certainly there are more plugins for Chrome, Eclipse, Jira and other platforms I don't even know? Sounds like sponsored content.

Comment: This was honestly the most confusing question of the bunch. Take Java as an example... do I tick all the boxes? None of them? I don't use Kubernetes just yet (still stuck on Marathon...) but technically the Microservices we have floating around could be deployed to Kubernetes, or AWS. Does that mean I develop "for" that platform?

Answer (score 35):

In "current total compensation" question, how do I specify which of "weekly, monthly, or yearly" it is? It doesn't let me enter anything but numbers in the input field.

Comment: Click on next, it will ask if the number is weekly/monthly/yearly.

Comment: That's terrible design.

Comment: Yes, that question really ought to be on the same page.

Comment: We changed it so that the three salary questions now appear on the same page. Thanks for bringing to our attention.

Comment: bi-weekly and twice monthly should also be options. With a bi-weekly schedule it is possible to get 26 or 27 paychecks in a year depending on when payday falls.

Comment: @JoeW just give the annual figure. I don't think they want to know when you get your pay check, just how much money you earn. In fact, I don't know why they don't just say "what's your annual compensation?"

Answer (score 31):

> In which city or town do you live? *This information will be kept private*.

Why do you care? I expect to read the 'why' here or in the survey results.

Comment: You are absolutely welcome not to share that kind of sensitive information. As to why we asked, we've used that data for results like these: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/05/developer-salaries-in-2018-updating-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/

Comment: OK, but that would need to be much more detailed than previous years, then. It only makes sense for large countries and large cities to ask if that is the level of reporting. I have no objection to filling it in, I just wonder why it would be useful.

Comment: @JuliaSilge the survey is not anonymous, right? Can't you just pull the location input from the user's profile?

Comment: @TimCastelijns The survey *is* anonymous. Your annual developer responses are not connected to your user profile in any way.

Comment: @JanDoggen It's true that so far, we've only been had enough respondents in large-to-medium cities, in large countries, to have enough signal to get useful results.

Comment: @JuliaSilge I'd be careful about using data about where someone lives and assuming that that is also where they work, especially for things like a salary calculator.

Comment: What if we don't live in a town? Like living on an oil platform, a submarine or the ISS? ;)

Comment: @Cœur It's a free-text field :-) I put that I was about an hour from the nearest major city in my state.

Comment: @TylerH [I always put my exact location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk5sw.png)

Comment: I thought that was a poor question - I live in a small town that is a suburb of a huge one (Tokyo prefecture but not Tokyo city) but actually commute to a different prefecture that (most likely) has lower salaries than the city centre, so I'm not sure how usable my answer would be.

Comment: That salary calculator has never seemed accurate to me - I wish I made anywhere near what it says I should (or had industry here which didn't just hire/lay-off contractors all the time). However - how is this attached to that if you never ask how much we make a year (week, hour, etc) or are you grabbing that information from somewhere else? (which again kinda points to profiles)

Comment: Or was there a salary question? Did not appear for me if there was (or I didn't scroll down enough)

Comment: @JGreenwell There was a salary question, [proof](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379297/608312).

Comment: ah, then I completely missed it or it did not show up on my screen, and I allow for both of these since I was using my tablet while waiting on a program to finish analyzing something, @JakeSteam (there are a few of those fyi mostly dealing with employment, like I didn't see the resume one)

Answer (score 28):

> Approximately how many people are employed by the company or organization you work for

- My regional office has 10-99 employees
- the range of employees of my country division is in 100-499;
- my company (international) has ~2000 employees;
- the company (WPP) which is controlling my company is ~130.000 employees.

Which range I had to choose?
Instinctively I chose the second option because it represents the set of people with whom I interact more or less habitually for work (*and that name is on my paycheck*), but I'm not sure if it's the right answer or not.

Comment: If it asks for "company or organization", it's not asking for the division you work at. Also, whoever owns the company is irrelevant. So I'd suggest you answer with ~2000 employees.

Comment: Just your company. How many people would you potentially work with directly? In most cases, holding or umbrella companies wouldn't contribute to that.

Comment: @TimPost potentially is the third one but never happened: actually is the second one

Comment: You might be able to go by the container that holds the highest person you are likely to ever report to. So if the farthest you'd ever appeal a management decision ends at your country, I think your country division is probably best. At some point in large organizations the connection exists mostly on spreadsheets, not really between people anymore, I think your best judgement at where that is would be fine. Over / understating isn't going to hurt anything in cases where it's kind of debatable.

Comment: I would also recommend the 2000 one, or maybe the 100 - 400 one. It's not asking how many people you work with on a daily weekly or monthly basis... just how many people are in your company. Certainly the 1st and 4th choices would be right out.

Comment: I work for a company that work for the government... I'll use the number of employees in the company, not the government.

Comment: This was an issue in last year's survey as well.

Comment: It clearly says "company" (not office or division) so why didn't you put the number of people in your company?

Comment: No, It clearly says company *or organization": how do you define "organization"?

Comment: @fcalderan Presumably "or organisation" is there for people who are not employed by a company - because, for instance, they work for a government body, or a charity (in a jurisdiction where charities aren't companies). I don't think the intent is for people who work for companies to just pick the size of their local office. Of course, in cases where you work for a company owned by another company, it *does* get a bit ambiguous...

Comment: I would say option 3 as that is the company that you work for, option 4 would be the company that owns the company you work for, where as 1 and 2 or sub units of the company

Comment: @fcalderan or also says "work for" not "in" or "at" so the answer would be whose name in on the pay-check and while it most certainly originates for the national unit it would be from the multinational company

Answer (score 27):

I know what is [turn it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8), but what is this:

---

[image]

---

Call what?

As for conversation I am not preferring any other other, either is useful depending on situation (didn't choose anything).

Comment: `what do you call an username?` would have been a silly question...

Comment: @jhamon, it = with who I am chatting? "What do you call *it* in chat" - is better question then (with pun on *it*). Or maybe "How do you call a person in chat"? Or giving first options "Person" and "Contact"? "Handle" and "Screen name" are pretty confusing here and aren't intuitive to figure out what answer is expected?

Comment: What do you call it: isn't this one more specific to the community?  Twitter calls them handles, SO calls it a "Display name".

Comment: Obviously "new" means "new to you"; someone going into very low power/cost embedded or compiler work could be encountering assembly for the first time since school.

Comment: @bmm6o, I don't have twitter. The author of question probably have ;) I couldn't figure out what answer is expected from context.

Comment: It would probably be better to separate both questions on different pages.

Comment: Naming things is hard. I think that question seeks to crowd source an answer :)

Comment: I felt this one was obvious, but yes it could easily have been better phrased, e.g. "in chat rooms, which of the following terms do you use to refer to someone's name?"

Comment: *"Which of the following terms/phrases do you prefer to use when identifying someone?"*, to throw a hat in the ring. I'd go as far as to put quotes around the responses to indicate that they're not meant in a development context.

Comment: @bmm6o Not to mention screenname and login are two different things that only sometimes coincide, and username can refer to either one.

Comment: Also, is "it" in chat or is "it" in general online?  I use different names depending on where I am --- here, I have a username; on Twitter, I have a handle; on Slack, I have a display name.

Comment: have to admit didn't like this question either after all depends on what it is used for, if i used it to log into the app then its a username rather than a login, if its a separate identifier then i prefer handle to screen name userID would be some auto assigned reference with not real world meaning to it

Answer (score 25):

Seeing Bash/Shell/Powershell together was a bit disturbing (a bit like it would have been to see "C/C++")

For next year maybe it would be better to propose:

- Bourne-shell and derivative (sh, bash, zsh ...)
- Windows batch
- Powershell
- other shell

Comment: Thank you, I never use Bash or Shell but I do use Powershell quite a bit (with .Net utilities) for quick "do what I want, not what you think I want!" windows scripts.

Comment: A command shell is a specific type of software, and all shell languages have similar traits due to the same niche. So it's only natural to couple them together if they don't care about finer distinction.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I understand but for some users it is hard to answer "Do you want to work with bash/powershell next year ?" because it is not clear if you let them choose the one they prefer. Also grouping them could easily be done in a post processing step.

Comment: maybe replace with CLI rather than giving names except as examples but splitting the CLI by technology was not the purpose of the questions

Answer (score 19):

> Thank you for completing the test survey

I used the link in the banner. Were my responses actually recorded?

Comment: They missed removing "test" from somewhere near the start of the survey.  I'm guessing you're fine and they just left it in more than one spot.

Comment: That was a typo that we inadvertently missed. We beta tested the survey a couple of weeks ago and forgot to take that language out. We've corrected it, and yes, your responses were recorded and do count.

Comment: How do you know for sure that the responses were recorded if the survey is anonymous? *ducks* ;)

Answer (score 10):

[image: manager]

Didn't quite understand the objective of this question. In generic sense, of course every individual knows what they're doing. But how am I suppose to guess and answer whether my manager really knows what he/she is doing or just pretending?

Comment: Reads like a gut-feel question.  *You know it when you see it*, especially in the context of dubious meetings, work requests, and other oddities that pop up which may cause doubt in your mind of your manager's competence.  It's reasonable to assume that they know what they're doing *in the beginning*, but over time, interacting with them will erase any assumptions you've had.

Comment: @Makoto Great point. But then what can be the best take away from the answer of this question?

Comment: "Do you trust your manager?"  Could be used to answer a question about confidence in one's manager versus whether or not one is seeking a new job or is unhappy in their current role.

Comment: @Makoto Your analysis makes sense but I am sure this question pops out of mind when there is some sort of _lack of trust_ already in the air and possibly he/she must have started for a more _trustable_ manager.

Comment: _"In generic sense of-coarse every individual knows what they're doing"_ Hahahahahahahha.... ha.

Comment: There is a bit of an English idiom in this question that may be more subtle than the survey devs realised. It really means "do you think your manager is competent?" It's not _actually_ about reading their minds ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand you are helping us to make a transit from StackOverflow to english.stackexchange but somehow _code-only_ answers have made us sound so miserable ;)

Comment: how about for next year 'How confident you and your immediate management share goals?'

Comment: @Pureferret That resonates better !!!

Comment: It's not the same question but that might also be a good question

Answer (score 8):

So, Wordpress is a platform but Drupal is a framework? Where does Joomla belong? Why not just merge all these "trending technology" questions into an interactive one and only categorize them in the report, if ultimately needed?

Also, I can't add more than one "Other" technology, which will lead to completely distorted results.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Following this question

> Think back to the last time you solved a coding problem using Stack Overflow, as well as the last time you solved a problem using a different resource. Which was faster?

there is this question

> About how much time did you save? If you're not sure, please use your best estimate.

The question asks how much time I saved using Stackoverflow against another scenario. But it is not clear if that other scenario is solving the problem using a different resource or if the scenario is trying to build the solution myself.

Comment: I guess one could see oneself also as a resource. I answered that SO helped me much more than any other service and that I saved something like 2 minutes maximum (I guess my everyday problems are rather simple to solve).

Answer (score 7):

One of the questions asked how confident I am in my skills as a developer (below average / average / etc). I think an interesting follow up question would be to ask "why?".

Comment: Quite right. Some possible options "because of my ability of solving bugs", "because I am able to deliver functionality quick enough", "because I can type correct code quickly", "because of my ability to design a fitting algorithm for my tasks", "because of the positive feedback I get from my clients / managers", "because of my knowing the tools needed" "because I can formulate a correct question on Stack Overflow if needed" etc...

Comment: Because I've never heard of the Dunning Kruger effect.

Answer (score 7):

> On average, how many hours per week do you spend on code review?

Will this be calculated against the amount of hours I work per week, multiple questions earlier? If not, this question should ask for a percentage instead.

Comment: One issue I had with this question is it depends greatly on the work I am doing. For example if I am writing an new section of code from scratch more time is going to be spent that week reviewing it than when it is ported as a whole to other projects since the main review is now done.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like pressing tab out of the survey questions focuses on the back button, not on the next button, which is unintuitive and unhelpful.

Answer (score 5):

At one point in the survey (completed, and I didn't screenshot), it says something like

> Which of these do you consider youself/best describes you:

And lists blindness, hearing etc.

And then (unless I'm mistaken), it repeats the question (***with the exact same wording***) but lists other conditions about mental/learning differences.

I came very close to putting one of the second set of options (e.g. Anxiety) as my 'other' to the first, before I saw both questions.

Could they be numbered, or more specific?

Comment: IIRC the first one was about physical conditions and the other about mental conditions. Thus was no puzzle for me. Though I imagine it could be for someone with one of those...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I must have not scrolled enough because it looked as though there were no questions below the first.

Answer (score 4):

Would it be interesting to have a question about the (coffee / energy drink) consumption of (users / developer / IT worker) in the survey?

Just asking.

Comment: That might be an interesting question to ask next year. Keep a lookout next fall for a Meta post asking people to recommend questions for the 2020 survey. We do our best to add the top vote-getters

Comment: Haven't we had this question before? It is requested each and every year... and it _is_ interesting to know. However I don't recall seeing any results regarding it. I had no coffee yet this morning though, so that could explain it. Brb.

Answer (score 3):

I think I am not alone who answered `what?` for this question.

```
Have you tried turning it off and on again?

What?
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhPejfTQfEA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtXtIivRRKQ

Comment: Took me a few seconds to understand what they were talking about but I did. "Turn it off and on again" is a stock phrase in IT support.

Comment: But, it is a question.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts on questions.

Questions about code reviews should also include options for workplaces where they are required by the company either for general policies or for industry requirements. I know in the financial industry more weight is put on a code review because of the potential impact malicious code can have on finances and I am sure there are other industries like this.

Also for unit testing it might be good to include options for places where it was not required in the past but they are slowly adopting it for new code and none of the answers provided really seem to fit that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, on a lot of the frameworks questions, how would you distinguish between me choosing not to respond and my not working with any of them?  I personally don't do any web development and don't particularly care to (I am a low level driver type) so pretty much all my work is in C/C++, and I have no desire to branch out (in that direction anyways).  There isn't a "None of the above" option, and the question isn't required.

Comment: I think it you leave it blank it means "None of the above..."

Answer (score 0):

In the Developer Survey Results 2019, the following is reported under "All of the Developers Are Above Average?":

> ...almost 70% of respondents say they are above average while less than
>   10% think they are below average. This is statistically unlikely with
>   a sample of over 70,000 developers who answered this question, to put
>   it mildly.

Putting aside the highly subjective nature of this question (because I think the results by demographic are worth analyzing), I have two comments:

**1) This conclusion seems a little cavalier.**

Under "When Did You First Visit Stack Overflow?" it's noted that

> our survey sample contains proportionally more long-time community
>   members than the population of Stack Overflow users in general.

and under "Methodology" we find that

> highly engaged users on Stack Overflow were more likely to notice the
>   links for the survey and click to begin it.

Isn't it possible that primarily long-time users of Stack Overflow who are also highly engaged might be more competent on average than their peers of similar experience levels who are not as engaged and therefore weren't as likely to take the survey?

It seems worth noting this as a possibility rather than simply disregarding these results as obviously erroneous.

**2) This conclusion - especially that last comment - seems disingenuous, even insulting.**

There's a known phenomenon where people tend to rank themselves slightly higher when compared to the rest of a group (at least in some cultures).

I assume that those responsible for creating and analyzing the survey either:

a) Knew about that phenomenon and asked this question anyway. (Thus, they should have expected a skewed result and mentioned it in the conclusion.)

OR

b) They didn't consider it. (At that point, why is the result statistically unlikely? Isn't this survey an example of an attempt to measure that kind of statistic? It's possible to have a room full of people and 70% of them be above average. How do we know this survey - or even SO itself - didn't create that kind of "room"?)

It seems like this conclusion is criticizing the survey respondents for not answering accurately or truthfully rather than questioning the validity of the question itself or the way that the pool of survey respondents was gathered.

Just to be clear, I found the survey very informative overall and appreciated the objective tone of the other conclusions. I also appreciate all the work that went into this survey and am glad to see that SO is dedicated to making the platform a place that is welcoming to all. And big props to SO for making the data public so anyone can do additional analysis on their own - I wish more companies were like that!

Comment: See also: [Please be more careful when interpreting the SO Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382731/please-be-more-careful-when-interpreting-the-so-developer-survey)

Comment: @TinyGiant Thanks for linking that! I was pretty sure I wasn't the only one who noticed these things, but I wasn't able to find that post.

Answer (score -5):

> Whats your age?

bigger/smaller signs dont work ...
So '>20' is somehow translated to somewhat like 'tg;20' after pressing next

Comment: I would also have liked to be able to enter a qualifier on this question

Answer (score -6):

I think you should add:

- Cosmos DB to the list of DB technologies (I added it under "other")
- Diploma/Higher Diploma to the list of post-school qualifications

Answer (score -15):

As an occasional user of Stack Overflow websites my greatest frustration is the zeal of moderators.

The website is elegant with little need for administration at all - content is easy to find, almost exclusively from google unless I fancy a little browsing for pleasure, in which case the similar q's links are great. The best content is naturally bubbled up to my attention via voting mechanism.

However, almost inevitably when I come across an interesting question, or am involved in discussion myself, the question is closed or answer removed with reference to some rules - off topic etc. Discouraging when you submit content, and frustrating when you'd like to see more in a discussion. Poor content will fade to the background anyway.... so why choke the site of the best ideas and deny its ability to evolve?

I am sure this particular thread breaks a bunch of rules as well, I'm surprised it has not been shut down.

Comment: _I am sure this particular thread breaks a bunch of rules as well, I'm surprised it has not been shut down._ This post is on meta, and meta is a lot more freeflowing. There are rules here of course as well, but the conventions of what is off topic, what is and isn't an answer, and format in general are a lot more relaxed here. On the main site it's different.

Comment: It should be noted that most of the actions you see are the results of fellow users actions, not moderators.\

Comment: Or rather, the site has a significant part of its moderation crowdsourced to the users. Which make it probably imperfect and not always consistent, but at least functioning

Comment: relevant about Magisch's comment : https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @Andrew ignorance of the [law](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) is no excuse.

Comment: @JoeW yes perhaps I've used an incorrect term - I mean the people whose only criticism is that a rule has been broken and so flag for closure etc without consideration for the value that contribution holds

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev My point is there are two many laws, which are rigid and applied in an overzealous manner. Unnecessarily constraining the sites and content. A (perhaps flawed) example is Twitter - simple with a few thoughtful constraints. They did not anticipate retweeting but userbase developed it. What would happen if you removed constraints on stackoverflow? Most rule applications I can only see as stifling usage and value.

Comment: There can be plenty of valuable posts that will still be deleted.  Stack Overflow doesn't try to be everything to everyone; there's a very specific focus, and everything else falls by the wayside.  That's why you have experts here, answering your questions.  Remove those constraints, and you lose those experts, and then, yes, we become the next Twitter.  That's not a good thing.

Comment: @fbueckert Tagging and other mechanisms do a wonderful job of filtering and searching for people to find relevant content. I don't agree that experts are here because there are not opinion based questions or whatever

Comment: Okay.  Then ask yourself why experts are here.  I'd recommend starting by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), which I see you haven't done yet.  Pay special attention to the top paragraph; that should give you a very strong hint as to what it is we do here.

Comment: @fbueckert - Point taken, my concern is not the moderators, it is the rules they are actually encouraged to apply.

Comment: Perhaps you should understand why we have the rules we do before you criticize them.  Learning why we work the way we do is critical to that understanding.  An analogy I've been using lately is that we're building a [castle out of cabinets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378851/what-should-be-done-to-change-peoples-perception-that-stack-overflow-is-hostile/378863#378863)

Comment: Populated by bees? Lots of tasty metaphors going on there. I do my work here and I'm trying to share the frustration that I experience, probably as a more typical stackoverflow user than yourself. The magic of this wonderful castle is that it has cabinets that are linked straight into google searches without any effort whatsoever. Good answers to my questions are upvoted. I can see potential problems with some open ended questions but I think most cases will enrich that castle. You can disagree but the obvious unquestioning zeal with which people treat the rules is in my opinion unhelpful.

Comment: Open ended questions attract low quality answers.  They are the rickety cabinets.  Allowing them would work against building a castle that withstands the test of time, and we'd have crumbling walls in no time.  There's nothing wrong with challenging rules, but it needs to be done with the understanding that how it currently works ensures that the castle is still here, far into the future.  If you're advocating for looser rules, you need to present a strong argument how that won't impact future viability.  This just comes off as a rant, otherwise.

Comment: You are confident that relaxing rules will result in a loss of quality, is there any empirical evidence to support that conviction? I am confident that applying rules is constraining content because by definition that is what they are doing.

Comment: That's easy; look at Yahoo Answers, or Quora.  They're both Q&A, with less (if any) rules on what can be asked.  Now ask yourself where you get better answers.  I think you know the answer to that.  And, yeah, the entire point of rules is to constrain content.  Content that we've deemed is problematic and doesn't fit well into a Q&A format.

Comment: That is interesting comparison, but I'm not convinced the key difference is rule application. Anyway - I can see there is not a lot of traction on this line of thinking so will drop off but good luck to you.

Comment: Partially, this is absolutely true, and some SE sites are worse than others. Partially, the content is easy to find and of high quality _because_ of moderation. Google ranks sites and search results based on credibility.