# Why can't I open the 2019 Developer Survey link?

Tags: support, survey-2019

When I click on the 2019 Developer Survey link:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: From the question announcing the survey - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey - "**If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages**". Have you tried disabling your ad-blocker?

Comment: There's also this answer - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379314/59303 - which suggests that it might be region locked in some way.

Comment: @ChrisF yup it's a country-based ban, But is this really necessary on the Stack Overflow Survey?

Comment: @ChrisF Would not it be better to use another server that does not block Stack Overflow users?

Comment: I will use a proxy :)
But I hoped that this ban would not come from the beginning on stackoverflow survey. Thank you @ChrisF

Comment: I'm not an employee so I can't comment on why the survey appears to be region locked. It must be something to do with the 3rd party software they're using.

Comment: A frame in the screenshot would be nice.

Comment: @AliAli Just saw in the answer below that Qualtrics, our third-party survey provider, does block Iran based on US sanctions between the two countries. We apologize for the inconvenience, and are glad you found a workaround.

Comment: Yup, I have completed the survey, here from Syria, thank you very much.

Comment: Just take a look at this [statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrNLY.png)

Comment: @devconcept Your feedback statement is truly wonderful :)

Comment: @devconcept and now you've just deanonymized your results within Stack Exchange Inc ;)

Comment: @pushkin I don't know where you live but anonymity and privacy are weird terms where I live... yes, even worse than the US Big Brother. You learn to live without them. SE is not law enforcement so I have no problems with that :P

Comment: A bit ironic when you can't answer "_How welcome do you feel on Stack Overflow?_" because you're blocked from accessing the survey that asks this.

Comment: Not fixed for 2020 Developer Survey.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

From the domain name it appears that Stack Overflow used *Qualtrics* for the developer survey. Here's an extract from [the Qualtrics terms of service](https://www.qualtrics.com/terms-of-service/):

> You warrant that you will not use the Services or Software in connection with any person, including yourself, that is (1) located in a country or region that is subject to comprehensive U.S. economic sanctions (including Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, and the Crimea region of Ukraine); or (2) a designated, denied, or otherwise restricted party, as specified under the laws and regulations identified above.

Given the location specified in your profile, I think this is evidence enough that Qualtrics has geo-blocked you.

I guess you can blame a combination of the US Government, extreme contemporary paranoia, and Stack Overflow's choice of third-party service (worldwide access *should* have been one of the selection criteria, and *should* have been checked!).

<strike>*(Emphasis on "guess"; I do not work for Stack Overflow, Qualtrics or the US government and am therefore merely speculating.)*</strike> Now confirmed by employee; apparently a deeper review will be taken next time before the choice to use this particular solution again is settled on. Please do apply due diligence, folks!

Comment: Thank you, Lightness, I appreciate your answer.
I hope that in the next year stackoverflow will use another server :)

Comment: Same here from Cuba. A little advice, use a VPN. This is clearly an honest mistake. I just hope that Stack Overflow don't make the same mistake next year.

Comment: It does show though that people aren't putting thought into internationalisation (even if it's just a token read-through of the very brief T&Cs of the selected third-party service), which is a shame for an organisation such as this. Worldwide access, you would think, should be one of the items on the checklist of "what does this service provide that we need?". It's a mentality thing. I do agree of course that ultimately it comes under the category of "accidental oversight".

Comment: This is the 2nd year that Stack Overflow used Qualtrics as our survey provider. Unfortunately, Qualtrics Terms of Service blocks countries where there are US sanctions. Based on our experience using them last year, we didn’t realize this was going to be an issue. We chose Qualtrics because our survey requires more specialized functionality than we can build in-house. Although the survey itself is large in scale, the team of employees who work on it is quite small, so we need to automate where we can. Next year, we will keep this issue in mind and determine if Qualtrics is the right fit.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Cool, nice one & thanks for the response. A welcome reminder I'm sure to keep reviewing things over time rather than assuming nothing's changed ;) (see also: compare prices before renewing your car insurance!)

Comment: FWIW building a survey is kind of trivial unless there's some magic going on behind the scenes that you can't build into your server environment for some reason

Comment: Any company that suggests turning off ad blocking in this day and age of malware serving ads should be avoided in my opinion.

Comment: @user1118321 Then you'd have to avoid half the web.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit probably branching, ip log and randomness.

Comment: Thank you @AnitaTaylor , Just a suggestion for the next year, taking into consideration the services of [SurveyMonkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com) and [YesInsights](https://www.yesinsights.com)

Comment: @JoelSpolsky Time to take a stand.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor In the meantime, perhaps rename [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/23/our-2019-developer-survey-is-open-to-coders-everywhere/?cb=1) from "Our 2019 Developer Survey is open to coders everywhere"!

Comment: geo-blocking sucks. Ipism http://en.speedypedia.info/Ipism

Comment: @devconcept [They did](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/05/the-2020-developer-survey-is-now-open).

Comment: It seems they also blacklist all Tor IPs, which is a shame because Tor users are not uncommon here.