# The 2020 Developer Survey Link is blocked in my country

Tags: support, status-reproduced, survey, survey-2020, geoblocking

I've been on SO for almost ~6 years. I'm sure there are many other, more active users from my country (and other countries) who are in the same situation as me.

Why have you used a service which blocks users in some countries? I believe that you believe Stack Overflow is for all developers from all around the globe.

[Seems like it happened last year too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379318/why-cant-i-open-the-2019-developer-survey-link)

Comment: Blame the states, not SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's still SO choice to use this service and not another elsewhere able to be used everywhere...

Comment: @Tensibai: It may well be possible that that service offers features others don't. The way this question is worded isn't constructive.

Comment: @Cerbrus possible yes, Presenting someone a link to a survey they won't be able to take and not giving a word about it sounds wrong to me anyway.

Comment: Sure, it's not ideal, but I strongly doubt it's that simple.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, I assume SO is capable of doing Geolocation as well as the survey site does and to present a page saying "Seem you're from X, due to US law Y, the survey system won't work for you, we're sorry for that but didn't found a better option" instead of directing toward the survey page ?

Comment: @Tensibai: Because geolocation is foolproof :P If anything, the survey provider should have a decent error page instead of that crap.

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't say that, I just mean that when you can reasonably guess there'll be a problem, it's nicer to handle it yourself than delegate it with no control, specially when you're aware the delegated handling is bad

Comment: @Tensibai: The questionnaire link is is a direct link to qualtrics on the blog. You'd have to go through a intermediate page to catch those cases... That seems excessive.

Comment: Use a VPN to access the survey.

Comment: @S.S.Anne that's what I did last year. But it not being fixed after a year means that SO thinks the data collected from these countries is not so important that they want to spend more money. I'm not going to waste my time to provide not that important information from now on.

Comment: Can you list in the question which countries Qualtrics blocks, as of 2020? [Blocked in Iran, Turkey (Cuba?, N Korea?, Syria?, Crimea region of Ukraine?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379318/why-cant-i-open-the-2019-developer-survey-link). Accessible from China, Russia(?). And are there ballpark estimates for the number of SO users living there? and survey response rate (via VPN)

Comment: [Do we need a tag \[geoblocking\] on Meta, given that SO and the SO Developer Survey/Qualtrics do it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393784/do-we-need-a-tag-geoblocking-on-meta-given-that-so-and-the-so-developer-surve)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. Yes, this is the same issue as what happened last year, and it is still something that is happening through Qualtrics, the survey provider that we are using. (Thanks yivi for your earlier response, your analysis was very accurate).

We decided not to switch from Qualtrics this year because we had already invested significant resources into automating data analysis with Qualtrics and do not have the bandwidth at this point to transfer the entire operation to another provider. We investigated using Qualtrics’ API to host the questions on our site (where there aren’t country-based restrictions), but their API was limited in the types of questions they supported. They don’t support our `LIKERT` questions that result in the most loved, wanted and dreaded technologies.

So we decided to continue hosting the survey on Qualtrics’ site, as we’ve done for the last two years. We regret that it is blocking some folks from taking the survey, and we will continue to keep this item on our list of things to investigate for future iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so there is nothing that you can do to solve this problem now, which is okay I guess, but please do anything you can to fix this problem for next year(s).

Comment: The survey is effectively blocked for me too.Your third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. Apparently I need to unblock Qualtrics in my Adblocker. My initial response might be construed as not very welcoming, so I am not going to post it here, but basically the answer is a resounding NO!

Comment: In the meantime I suggest removing such phrases as _"we want our survey to represent everyone who codes"_ from the introductory text, since the company is fully aware that they are not providing that opportunity, not including everybody.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Better start localizing the survey in a couple of hundred languages then.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ideally, yes, but there's certainly a middle ground. I put forth that there exists a gaping chasm between "the survey is only available in the _de facto_ international language of the internet", and "you are literally not able to access the survey at all from your present location".

Answer (score 12):

It seems rather daft Qualtrics interpreting that gathering survey responses for their American clients is a "technology export". I would understand not providing their service to clients (as SO) in Iran, but the location of the surveyed end-users seems rather less relevant.

But of course I'm sure their legal counsel knows better. I'm not a lawyer, not American, and probably very ill advised to give any kind of legal advise to absolutely anyone.

Last year [Anita Taylor mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379318/why-cant-i-open-the-2019-developer-survey-link#comment665237_379352) they hadn't expected this to be a problem, but that they were going to evaluate the possibility of changing providers for the following (this) year.

Since they haven't changed providers, we have to assume they either:

- didn't find a provider that didn't block users in Iran (among other countries)
- that those that didn't perform that kind of geo-blocking did not provide all the features that SO needed to have perform their survey.

We all know that in the end with this kind of choice is always a balancing act. No choice is perfect, but you choose the one where the benefits outweigh the total cost by as much as possible.

I agree it would be nice to have an official statement from SO regarding their choice of survey provider, and if they will keep evaluating different choices in the future. (Or maybe try to convince Qualtrics that they are not really exporting technology to Iran when Iranians answer survey questions?)

Comment: FTR Surveymonkey has the same kind of limitation in their terms of use (I didn't check others companies, that's just to said Qualtrics are not the only ones with this kind of limitation)

Comment: Why they using providers in the first place? I mean why they didn't build their own survey system (of course I don't know what exactly the provider provide for SO survey, server or survey system, or something else. but in any case they can use their own)

Comment: @Mehdi As with anything, it's a matter of balancing cost and benefit. Usually, a company would focus their efforts in their core business needs, and for things that are not part of that core would evaluate external solutions built by experts in that solution domain. To make an **extremely naive** comparison: companies that are not in the furniture business buy tables from external suppliers instead of building their own.

Comment: Building own survey webapp is doable for SO, more so since you’re anyways unable to benefit from Qualtrics ootb (API etc.)