# Can we have two versions of Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey

Since there were people complaining of the length of the Survey last year, but I am sure there are a lot of others who don't mind taking a longer survey, could we have two versions of the Developer Survey next year, a short one and a more detailed one for people willing to answer more questions?

I am asking this because I know there are people with not that much spare time to answer a lot of questions, but there are also a lot of important questions that should not be skipped.

So, **would it be feasible to have two different versions of Developer Survey 2020, a 'standard length' one and, *for those who choose to opt for it*, a longer one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anita Taylor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379281/1505120) claimed:

> We heard you loud and clear when you asked for a shorter survey. We did our best to deliver without sacrificing valuable insight, and we shaved off about five minutes from last year’s survey. The survey should take about 25 minutes to complete.

So, if to be believed, for 2018 relative to 2019 there was clearly at least 5 minutes worth of, at best, 'nice to have but not essential' and a simple comparison of the two surveys should indicate what could be included in a 'long' version but excluded from a 'short' one.

An option to choose would also preselect for those prepared to invest yet more of their time and facilitate an even longer survey than last year's. Nowadays information is power and usually grabbed by one and all at every opportunity, so I can image there were even questions that some would have liked included last year that missed the cut for fear of making that survey even more cumbersome.

The suggestion is clearly viable from a theoretical perspective, even though possibly not from a technical or practical one. Unless the reduction 2018 > 2019 merely cut out what was never required in the first place the suggestion merits serious consideration.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not a developer so have never responded.</sub>

Comment: From a technical perspective, I don't think it would be that hard. I mean it can be the same survey, and as some pages have the options to completely skip the questions, this pages should not be displayed at all in the shorter version. 

Aside from the subject, I don't know why is this negative feedback about the question above, as I was just trying to help.

Answer (score 4):

What are the most important things to ask, though? That's always going to depend on endeavor, or why you're looking at the data. If you're trying to get a general overview of what frameworks all the front-end web folks that responded are grooving with, then you'd be interested in that segment.

If you're trying to see if the slice of the developer world our survey represents has changed in terms of demographics in some way, then you're after different data entirely.

Fewer questions on *all* aspects *might* be possible without degrading the usefulness of the information? I'm honestly not sure. I know the survey is already highly optimized for brevity.

Unless you can really clearly define what's most important *to everyone* and show that information alone as being useful on it's own, it's rather hard to talk about how we'd go about accomplishing that.

Comment: I dont think the OP was asking to make the survey next year shorter than this year, but rather have a survey that is _longer_ than this years survey _as well as_ a survey that is the same or similar length as the one this year.

Comment: @TinyGiant this is actually true. Is the question a bit unclear?

Comment: @meJustAndrew your question sounds like you're asking for a shorter survey, except for the very last sentence.

Comment: @TheWanderer I am asking for a longer survey, I mean I had the time, and I would have invested it in the survey, because I am somehow aware of the importance of detailed data about different development aspects. I mean this year, the questions regarding **ethics** were removed from the survey, and I think this is an important aspect that needs to be kept, as others too...