# When is the 2019 Developer Survey closing?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2019

When is the 2019 Developer Survey closing?

As mentioned in post *[Take the 2019 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey)*, *The survey will be open until February 12* (Year: Unknown)

[The World Clock — Worldwide](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/) suggests Tuesday, February 12th, 2019 is history now.

[The survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_1RGiufc1FCJcL6B?utm_medium=so-meta&utm_source=so-owned&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019&award=b75485e89fad4ffaa53eb11e9c3fd828&site=stackoverflow.com) seems still open:

[image: survey]

Comment: They left the survey running a really long time last year, too. Not sure what the reason is behind this. I speculated last year that it might be related to lower-than-expected participation, but I never got confirmation of that, and it wouldn't be lower-than-expected the second year in a row. Results don't typically get published until mid-March, so...6-8 weeks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The survey is now closed.

Thus, the answer to your question seems to be February 14, 2019.

Comment: I think you are right. Seems the post entittled _Take the 2019 Developer Survey_ is also removed from **FEATURED ON META** section.

Comment: Still listed as Featured for me! The mystery continues...? No, it's still pretty much over.

Comment: @Zim Caching. It's not featured anymore. The tag was removed before I posted this answer.